# SVM Quadprog Matlab unbound error

Tags: matlab

I'm implementing SVM via matlab, not using svmtrain.
I randomly generate separable data and its label.
Then solve quadratic problem using quadprog. Code is below.

```
options=optimoptions('quadprog', 'Algorithm', 'active-set', 'Display', 'none','MaxIter',500);
[xsol,fsolve,exitflag,output] = quadprog(-H,-f,[],[],Aeq,beq,lb,[],[], options);
```

Output is below

```
output = 
         iterations: 1
    constrviolation: 0
          algorithm: 'active-set'
            message: [1x96 char]
      firstorderopt: 1.1861e+21
       cgiterations: []
exitflag =
    -3
```

I can't understand why the problem is unbounded. I just put `H`, `f`, `Aeq`, `beq`, and `lb` same in the reference; Support-Vector Network written by Corinna Cortes and Vladimir Vapnik.
Is there any method to fix this problem?